# Array to remove a number on arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino-uno

How can I print and remove this number in array? I am trying to do the array but it is not working:

I have an `if` with this number:

```
 if (conteudo.substring(1) == "44 46 00 22")
```

**so i would like print this number in my array and remove after.**

```
int  ledArray[] = {44 46 00 22,44 46 00 23,44 46 00 24}; 
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{ 
{
     Serial.println(ledArray[0]);
}
```

Comment: I requested to move this question to StackOverflow

Comment: do you want to print 44 46 00 22 and then have the display change to 44 46 00 23 after some time? Do you want to replace 22 with 23?

Comment: I want 1 sample removing forever and another removing for 24hrs :) please

Comment: is the space between the numbers important? Do you want 4 numbers for each member of your array 44, 46,00, 22 or do you want one number 44460022

Comment: Please provide a complete [repro] and complete example for what you want to achieve.

Comment: yeah the space it is important

Answer (score 1):

A couple of different points.

1) Not sure if this will answer your question, but is the issue that you should have `ledArray[i]` in your code...

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){ { 
  Serial.println(ledArray[i]);
}
```

instead of

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){ { 
  Serial.println(ledArray[0]);
}
```

2) Have a look at [this page](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println/) which describes `Serial.println`

3) The `int` array does not work the way you want it to. It will not include spaces - each member of the array is simply a different integer number with the type `int`

It seems like you have 4 values and they could well be HEX rather than decimal (decimal 0-255 : HEX 00 - FF) so I suggest a two dimensional array of the numbers....

```
 // choose one of the definitions below depending on whether you numbers are decimal or HEX - in HEX the numbers start 0x
int ledArray[3][4] = {{44, 46, 00, 22},{44, 46, 00, 23},{44, 46, 00, 24}};
//    int ledArray[3][4] = {{0x44, 0x46, 0x00, 0x22},{0x44, 0x46, 0x00, 0x23},{0x44, 0x46, 0x00, 0x24}};

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  { 
    for(int j = 0; j<4;j++)
     { 
       Serial.println(ledArray[i]);
     }
    // insert something here for a pause before you print the next set of numbers
  }
```